# datepicker last day of the month styling

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

[So basically I've done my best to style the datepicker for my project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC8tw.png)

[My last hurdle is to style the last days of the month if they're in range of the selection to be all curvy like all the other days at the start and end of a week.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7rNc.png)

Can anyone please help with this problem? Any sort of help is highly appreciated thank you.

This is my stylesheet.

```
.wpm-datepicker {
  font-weight: 600;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  width: 100%;

  .bs-datepicker-multiple {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: $color-light-blue-grey 0 6px 13px;
    flex-basis: 50%;

    &:first-of-type {
      margin-right: 20px;
    }

    &:nth-of-type(2) {
      margin-left: 20px;
    }
  }

  .bs-datepicker-container {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .bs-datepicker-head {
    background-color: #0f2332 !important;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    padding: 17px 10px;
    height: auto;

    &::after {
      content: unset;
    }

    button:nth-of-type(1) span,
    button:nth-of-type(4) span {
      color: transparent;
      left: -12px;
      top: 10.5px;
      display: inline-block;
      border-right: 2px solid #ffffff;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      border-radius: 1px;
    }

    button:nth-of-type(1) span {
      transform: rotate(135deg);
    }

    button:nth-of-type(4) span {
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
  }

  .bs-datepicker-body {
    border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
    border: 0.1px solid #e5e5e5;
    padding: 19px;

    table th {
      color: #970202 !important;
      font-weight: 600;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      padding: 14px 0;
    }

    table th:first-of-type,
    table td:first-of-type {
      display: none;
    }

    table td {
      color: #0f2332 !important;
    }

    table td span .is-other-month {
      color: #aab9c3 !important;
    }

    table.days span {
      line-height: 31px;
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    table.days span.in-range:not(.select-start)::before {
      background: #ffcaca !important;
      right: 19px;
      height: 24px;
      top: 4px;
    }

    table td::before,
    table td span::before {
      left: -20px !important;
    }

    table td span.selected,
    table td.selected span,
    table td span[class*="select-"]::after,
    table td[class*="select-"] span::after,
    table td.is-highlighted:not(.disabled):not(.selected) span,
    table td span.is-highlighted:not(.disabled):not(.selected) {
      background-color: #ffcaca;
      width: 24px;
      height: 24px;
      line-height: 24px;
    }

    table td span.is-other-month,
    table td.is-other-month span {
      background-color: transparent !important;
    }

    table td span.selected,
    table td.selected span,
    table td span[class*="select-"]::after,
    table td[class*="select-"] span::after {
      background: #e60000 !important;
    }

    table td:nth-of-type(2) span::before {
      border-radius: 16px 0 0 16px;
      left: 8px !important;
    }

    table td:nth-of-type(8) span::before {
      border-radius: 0 16px 16px 0;
      right: 4px !important;
    }

    table td:nth-of-type(8) span.select-end::before {
      right: 10px !important;
    }

    table.days span.in-range.select-end::before {
      right: 20px;
    }
  }

  bs-days-calendar-view {
    &:nth-of-type(1) bs-datepicker-navigation-view {
      display: flex;

      button {
        padding: 0 4px;
        font-size: 14px;

        &:nth-of-type(1) {
          padding-left: 24px;
          padding-right: 10px;
        }

        &:nth-of-type(1) span {
          bottom: 2px;
        }

        &:nth-of-type(3) {
          padding: 0;
        }
      }
    }

    &:nth-of-type(2) bs-datepicker-navigation-view {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-end;

      button {
        padding: 0 4px;
        font-size: 14px;

        &:nth-of-type(3) {
          padding: 0;
        }

        &:nth-of-type(4) {
          padding-left: 30px;
          padding-right: 10px;
        }

        &:nth-of-type(4) span {
          bottom: 2px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My component has this for the bsConfig

```
this.bsConfig = {
      containerClass: "wpm-datepicker",
    };
```

And this how I have it for my markup.

```
<bs-daterangepicker-inline
      [bsConfig]="bsConfig"
      [bsValue]="bsRangeValue"
    ></bs-daterangepicker-inline>
```

Comment: Please show us some code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Grumpy I've edited my post, hope it's clear enough.